# How to determine ergative verbs

Tags: grammar

As a non-English speaker, it's sometimes hard to determine what style of a verb is meant in sentences written/said by native speakers of English.

For example, there are ergative verbs in English. 
My question is how to determine a given verb in a sentence is an ergative verb or not? Should I match it with a list of those ergative verbs? Is there such a list?

As an instance, is *evaluate* an ergative verb?

Comment: @Lawrence I think OP has in mind the difference between "You evaluate the formula as X" and "The formula evaluates to X".

Comment: This is general reference, possibly [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) fodder, but no, 'evaluate' is not an intransitive verb and so cannot be ergative. Ergative verbs can be used both transitively and intransitively; the same noun can be used as the direct object of the former (transitive) and the subject of the latter (intransitive) with equivalent meaning: "You evaluate X" doesn't mean the same thing as "X evaluates".

Comment: @JEL: the meanings are almost the same, so I think calling *evaluate* ergative in this sense is perfectly reasonable. Why don't you think the meaning isn't the same?

Comment: What @Peter said. I don't have any real problem with *Tom's algorithm evaluates easily with integer arguments*, OR *Dick evaluates Tom's algorithm easily with integer arguments*, and it seems to me that fits the definition of "ergative verb". Come to that, much the same principle applies to *You can't compute function X* vs *Function X does not compute*, or *You can sort this table easily* vs *This table sorts easily*.

Comment: ...per [Peter's comment some years ago](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124695/what-is-the-way-to-understand-ergative-verbs#comment257009_124695) contrasting *He ran the restaurant well* and *The restaurant ran well*, with a bit of "give and take" you can make a case for an awful lot of verbs being "ergative" (to the extent that it's a useful classification at all).

Comment: @PeterShor, I think the senses of 'evaluate' are distinct in the two expressions. The second seems to be a jargon sense from mathematics meaning simply 'can be expressed numerically', while the first means that an agent has calculated a definite value, not merely that such a value *can be expressed*. You disagree?

Comment: @Jel: I disagree. I don't think *"the formula evaluates"* is used very much at all. It would be *"the formula evaluates to 16"*, which corresponds to *"I evaluate the formula and obtain 16"*. So the grammar is slightly different in the intransitive and transitive uses.

Comment: @PeterShor, well, I see what you're driving at, but think the distinction between 'intransitive use' and 'intransitive sense' should be maintained for lexical and pedagogical reasons, if no other. 'Evaluate' has no intransitive sense, although to be sure it has intransitive uses.

Comment: @JEL: I see what you're saying, but I don't see why that means we can't call the word *ergative*.

Comment: @PeterShor, okay, so your claim is either that "the syntactic relationship that holds between (1) [the stone moved] and (3) [John moved the stone] is ‘ergative’: the subject of an intransitive verb ‘becomes’ the object of a corresponding transitive verb, and a new ergative subject is introduced as the ‘agent’ (or ‘cause’) of the action referred to" is incorrect, or that 'evaluate' has an intransitive sense (not listed in any lexicon I've checked)? Or am I missing another possibility? It wouldn't be the first time for me for that, of course.